# How to migrate data between two tables in Cassandra properly

Tags: cassandra, data-migration, cassandra-2.1

I have to change the schema of one of my tables in Cassandra. It's cannot be done by simply using `ALTER TABLE` command, because there are some changes in primary key.

So the question is: How to do such a migration in the best way?

Using `COPY` command in cql is not an option in here because dump file can be really huge.

Can I solve this problem by not creating some custom application?

Comment: I think you can't do it directly in cassandra. You have to use and external tool like flyway, cassandra-migration (npm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Guillaume has suggested in the comment - you can't do this directly in cassandra. Schema altering operations are very limited here. You have to perform such migration manually using one of suggested there tools OR if you have very large tables you can leverage Spark.

Spark can efficiently read data from your nodes, transform them locally and save them back to db. Remember that such migration requires reading whole db content, so might take a while. It might be the most performant solution, however needs some bigger preparation - Spark cluster setup.